# .net 8 aspire database issue

Tags: c#, .net, .net-8.0, dotnet-aspire

I experimenting with.net 8 aspire currently.

I am following Microsoft documentation. I did a simple project with Backend api, frontend, and Redis cache.

```
var builder = DistributedApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

var cache = builder.AddRedisContainer("crediscache");

var weatherapi = builder.AddProject<Projects.WeatherApp_Api>("weatherapi");

builder.AddProject<Projects.WeatherApp_Web>("frontend")
    .WithReference(weatherapi)
    .WithReference(cache);
```

All works fine. By working fine I mean it can deploy everything on the local environment with a Redis container on the docker desktop and when I use the command line `azd init`, it creates the required infrastructure files and when I run `azd up` it deploys everything correctly on azure.

But when I AddSqlServerContainer like:

```
var database = builder.AddSqlServerContainer("database");
```

It creates the database on the docker desktop but,  when I run `azd init`, it returns an error:

```
ERROR: unsupported resource type: sqlserver.server.v1
```

Is this because it is still in preview or is it an azd issue, or is it something wrong I am doing?

I use Visual Studio Enterprise 2022 Preview 17.9.0 Preview 1.0 with the latest azd version "azd version 1.5.0 (commit 012ae734904e0c376ce5074605a6d0d3f05789ee)"

It compiles fine, there are not code issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is actually in azd.  azd doesn't support the SqlServer resource type yet, the following azd GitHub issue is tracking implementation:

https://github.com/Azure/azure-dev/issues/3020

Answer (score 1):

We have made some progress in SQL Server support in preview 2. If you use `AddSqlServerContiner(...)` we will now add a `container.v0` resource to the manifest which `azd` uses to deploy the application.

Unfortunately we did not get support for the `AddDatabase(...)` extension method in `azd` (which results in a `sqlserver.database.v0` resource in the manifest). Which means that options are limited in preview 2.

In preview 2 we are introducing some variations of the `AddX` methods which are not quite so container focused and are instead focused on adding the abstract concept of a resource to the app model (so you might use `AddSqlServer(...)` instead of `AddSqlServerContainer(...)`.

We did the app model work in preview 2 and we are hoping in preview 3 that we can make progress towards these resource types deploying in `azd` as managed services such as Azure SQL Database which is more appropriate for production workloads.

For right now, if you want SQL Server to deployed via `azd` you would need to use `AddSqlServerContainer(...)` and not append `AddDatabase(...)`.

I am hopeful that this information will be obsolete soon ;)